# .htaccess route path configuration for laravel project

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, subdomain

It may be one of trickiest question it ever asked about htaccess file configuration, but it needs a little bit effort,
the question is How I'm supposed to redirect an URL (example) **localhost/storage/*{id}*/public/*{username}*/** to ***{username}*.localhost** ?

and what should I use to get succeded to get the right redirection path?

Thanks :3

Answer (score 0):

You can create a storage symlink using `php artisan storage:link`

This will reate a smybolic link from `storage/app/public` to `public/storage`.

Therefore when you save something into `localhost/storage/public/{id}/{username}/` it could be accessed at `localhost/storage/{id}/{username}`

Let me know if there is any reason why it is not enough.

Comment: okay, let's say this is just what and how I was thinking at first, but the goal of this project
giving to each user who are registered, a unique subdomain, so everyone from the net let's say, can get access to that specific user stored files ... so it must be like **{slug-user-name}**.localhost

Comment: I think it is possible that way, just you need to adapt some middleware, to check if the user is trying to get into its own storage

Comment: well check this one ! 
it may be useful one day !

https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/?share=b1c2d3b8-6f22-4447-864e-763ef5779dee